# Value of property Roles must be of type List of String || AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

While Trying to Deploy AWS SAM the Stack creation is failing with the following error:

**Value of property Roles must be of type List of String**

As the Template file is very big I am just giving the part for the Policies Section

```
  Policies:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: !Join ['',['lambdaExecutionPolicy',!FindInMap [Variables,Vid,value]]]
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 'dynamodb:Query'
            Resource: '*'
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 'logs:*'
            Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:*:*:*'
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 's3:GetObject'
              - 's3:PutObject'
            Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::*'
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
              - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
              - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
            Resource: '*'
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
              - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
              - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
            Resource: '*'
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 'sns:Publish'
            Resource: !Ref mysubscription
      Roles: !Ref lambdaexecutionrole'
```

While Executing the CFT [image]

Comment: How did it go? Did the roles worked out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per docs, [Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html#cfn-iam-policy-roles) has the form of:

```
  Roles: 
    - String
```

Thus in your case, you should have:

```
Roles: 
  - !Ref lambdaexecutionrole
```

or

```
Roles: [!Ref lambdaexecutionrole]
```